# VSIX Performance Profiling

Tags: c#, visual-studio, profiling, performance-testing, vsix

How can I profile VSIX Extensions?
I already tried JetBrains dotTrace and the VisualStudio internal performance profiler.
The problem is, that the two tools only show the running times of several internal visual studio threads without any detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use Timeline profiling mode in dotTrace and then search for your methods in snapshot?